# Unable to show DateTimePicker

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, dojo

I have a problem when loading jsp in the console I found:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.struts2.dojo.components.DateTimePicker
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.struts2.dojo.components.DateTimePicker

My jsp seems:

```
<% @ Page language = "java"%> 
<% @ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/ struts-tags"%> 
<% @ taglib prefix = "sx" uri = "/ struts-dojo-tags"% >

<html>
 <head>
  <title> <s:text name="app.title"/> </ title>
  <sx:head/>
 </head>
 <body> 
  .... 
  <sx: datetimepicker name = "formation.date" label = "format (yyyy-MM-dd)" 
       DisplayFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" /> 
  .... 
 </body>
```

and I put struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6.jar in WEB-INF/lib Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you `struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.3.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: No I have put struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6.jar in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: There is space in the `uri` attibute value: `/ struts-tags` and `/ struts-dojo-tags`. Remove that and try it.

Comment: Struts2 dojo plugin is deprecated. Take a look at Struts2 jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have given space between `sx:` and `datetimepicker` . Remove the space and try once again

Also You have given format as

```
DisplayFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

change it to

```
displayFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```